# Gibbs sampler, issue with a full conditional

Tags: statistics, markov-chains, conditional-probability, statistical-inference, bayesian

I am implementing a gibbs sampler and I have a Laplace likelihood (iid data). We can think of a Laplace distribution as a mixture of normals according to https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/016214508000000337.

So I will assume: